# Setting Lifecycle configuration for Existing S3 Buckets in CloudFormation template file

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I want to set the Amazon S3 bucket lifeCycle configuration where the objects will be deleted after 6 months through CloudFormation.
I want to add this configuration to an existing bucket using the following script.

```
{
   "AWSTemplateFormatVersion":"2010-09-09",
   "Description":"Set Lifecycle Configuration",
   "Resources":{
      "S3Bucket":{
         "Properties":{
            "BucketName":"amazon-connect-test",
            "AccessControl":"Private",
            "LifecycleConfiguration":{
               "Rules":[
                  {
                     "Id":"DeleteAfter6Months",
                     "Status":"Enabled",
                     "ExpirationInDays":180
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         "Type":"AWS::S3::Bucket"
      }
   }
}
```

but the problem is that it will create a new S3 bucket and then add the LifeCycle.
I want the script that will add the LifeCycle configuration to an existing S3 bucket.
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on @elias's answer, refer this [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/successfully-import-an-s3-bucket-as-an-aws-cloudformation-stack.html) which explains about importing an existing S3 bucket as an AWS CloudFormation stack. Make sure to add the attribute "DeletionPolicy" in the resource of CloudFormation template as described in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

To edit existing resources that are currently "unmanaged" by CloudFormation, first you need to [bring it into CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html)

You can manage your resources regardless of where they were created without having to delete and re-create them as part of a stack

Comment: Could you please update it for me as I am new to CloudFormation Scripting? thanks @elias

Comment: It's not about editing the script. You have to import the existing S3 bucket into CloudFormation management in your AWS account first